# strange cakePHP layout issue (ajax)

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, layout

I have this code:

```
// controller  
function contact($token) {
  $this->layout = 'ajax';
}

// contact element
<some html, no php>

// contact view html + javascript
<script type=".....">
....
$.post(
    $(this).attr("href"),
    null,
    function(data){
              $(data).appendTo($(".contact_store_link").parent()).fadeIn();
            }
    );
</script>

<!-- the relevant html -->
<dd><a class="contact_store_link" href="/stores/contact">link title</a></dd>
```

The problem is that regardless of the `$this->layout = 'ajax';` directive, the returned layout is the default layout that is set in the `appController.beforeFilter()` function.

The thing is, except of the layout, the rest of the code is working just fine. the correct controller + action + passed arguments. the element and view also works fine and the returned data contains the processed data, just in the wrong layout.

clearing the tmp folder didn't help.
I also verified that the ajax layout is as it should be (and works in another controller.action+view set).

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
function contact($token) {
  $this->layout = 'ajax';
  $this->render("ajax_view_name", FALSE);
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I believe that for Ajax requests you do not need a layout, but a View, is exactly what the `render()` method does. The two parameters refer to the view and layout respectively. That is, I believe you do not need the first line, since the second overrides the first.

Comment: the MVC way requires the view, and the cake way the layout. tho i will accept your answer in the end, i removed the V so i may get other answers..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `$this->layout = null;` in the action that is being called in the ajax request?

Answer (score 0):

What about `$this->autoLayout = false;`, then render the layout you want.

CakePHP defines `autoLayout = true` by default in the `lib\View\View.php` file. Hope it helps.